# When is the best time to take down a tower if you're winning in your lane?

Tags: league-of-legends

When is the best time to take down a tower in your lane if you're winning the lane?

Comment: As phrased, this question is awfully vague and unlikely to result in a factual single answer, which makes it a poor fit for the site.

Comment: @lilserf Couldn't somebody model the laning phase in the current and run simulations to estimate when would be an optimal time to take a tower? It may be more work than anybody on Arqade is willing to undertake, but I think a factual answer is possible. But even without that, a thorough and well-documented answer based on experience is still useful for other users.

Comment: There is no "correct" answer to this question.  It has a variety of factors such as map pressure, summoner spells (teleport), scaling of yourself and your opponent.

Comment: In addition, it depends on what lane you are talking about also.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is if you are winning your lane (like killing the other champion several times), take the tower when your minions manage to destroy it on their own.

Reason: You want the laning phase to last as long as possible since you are winning the lane, your advantage of your lane versus their lane is only going to continue to snowball to an advantage for your team.

Guideline: Varies for different lanes, but I would say don't take the turret before you reach level 11.  By this time, you have the second level of your ultimate and can make a bigger impact on the rest of the game.  Generally if your team is ahead or even, taking the outermost tower is a certainty to occur.  I might make an exception for mid-lane as that middle tower gives so much control over the map and you can really start controlling their jungle to make up for if they freeze the lane and try to deny you.

Answer (score 2):

I dunno why people think that taking a tower fast is bad. Why wouldn't your opponent NOT do so with a tower? I think that taking the tower asap and knowing how to handle it is the best you can do. My reasons:

1. 150 gold is A LOT in low levels
2. Do not push the lane, it will force your enemy to stay around mid = your jungler will be very happy.
3. just call mias and your allies wont get ganked, place some wards maybe. You will deny farm from the enemy and him roaming without succesfully ganking = gg for him.
4. Super freedom of gank for you. Push the lane and go gank to your hearts content until the minions get close to your tower.

The key to pull this out correctly is knowing how to handle map awareness and the minion waves.

Answer (score 2):

This is my opinion.

---

### Resources.

[image]

1. Link to a different table here =
   http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Farming
2. Link to turret information here
   =http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Turret

---

## Explanation

---

### What do I gain from killing the turret?

There are four things you will gain from killing an enemy turret, Gold, Experience, Map control, Map Pressure.
Now lets analysis this real quick.

### Gold & Experience

1. When an Outer turrets is destroyed, each member of the destroyer's
   team gains 100 global gold, and 150 gold are split among the players
   who participate in destroying the turret. No experience is gained.
2. When an Inner turret is destroyed, each member of the destroyer's
   team gains 30 experience, each member of the destroyer's team gains
   125 global gold, and 100 gold are split among the players who
   participate in destroying the turret.
3. When an Inhibitor turret is destroyed, each member of the
   destroyer's team gains 100 experience and 175 gold. Players
   participating in the destruction of the turret do not gain
   additional gold.

---

### Map control and Everything Else

So this depends on many things, First of which side of the map you are in, Second How is your team doing overall, and Last Which lane you are in.
If for example your entire team aside from your own lane is performing poorly destroying the turret means that the lane opponent you were fighting no long needs to be in you lane and if your entire team was not performing well that means that him or being there will give him or her a chance to get back in the game so consider that. This I feel applies to all champions but more so for champions with large amounts of cc and considerable range or high burst. So if you laning a veigar and he no longer needs to defend the turret then he will probably kill someone regardless how unfed or behind he is just from the high damage his spells do that being said keeping someone like veigar in lane can be bad as well if you are not able to make him miss cs in lane or under turret as his q scales with his ap. NOW in saying this I want to also mention Nasus who has a Q that also stacks as well as Draven(Passive gives him bonus gold on kill bases on how many axes he caught consecutively) then Tristana with her range.

---

See where I am going. Sometimes you have to sacrifice the Gold and well all the bonuses you get so that you can keep a late game terror in check, yes you maybe able to kill them but destroying the turret gives them the opportunity to either come back in team-fights or just farm safely on their side of the map UNLESS you are able to successfully freeze the lane but you will not because you will be ganked you will want to help other lanes and well a lot of things can go down, you must have the forsight to look beyond the gold and exp and look at what you can deny, when you have found that they wont gain anything then by all means take it down! However to cut all of this very short it comes down to a few things.
How good your team late or mid game is depending on when you think it may end if your team has an advantage in a late game then you want to deny as much as possible and while gold and exp and some map pressure and vision is nice, the exp and gold you deny by keep their turret alive while also keep yours up and keep them from farming by freezing. This is far better for your team in some cases. If your team has a poor late game or they do not scale well or do not team fight well etc then well you want to end it as soon as possible. That is all there is to it in the end. How quickly you want the game to end. However just because you want the game to end quickly it may not go that way so consider that as well as what I have already mention and also what your guts tell you because most of the time the are right!

Answer (score 0):

This is an important question, while taking down a  tower is usually a good thing, sometimes it is better to leave your opponents tower up. In bot lane leaving your opponents tower up prolongs the laning phase giving you a longer opportunity to farm and increase your gold advantage. Taking down an opponent's Tower top or mid lane gives those very dangerous champions free reign to roam and cause trouble for your teammates. Generally its best to take out a tower when you are ready to leave your laning phase or your team is in need of the global gold to push better and initiate team fights. Its always important to note the champs you are laning against and you CS when determining where or not to take out a turret. I hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

If it is still early and you want to deny your opponent CS just let the tower continue to kill minions and farm as you can. While your lane is pushed (since you have an advantage) you want to take advantage by going for other objectives/helping the closest lane.

i.e. ganking or helping fight for enemy buff with your jungler/other laners and pushing for Dragon kills/push other lanes if they want them pushed or need to back.

If you are levels ahead of your laning opponent and feel safe and your teammates are having trouble in other lanes then you might want to take tower so that you can give your team global gold and also help them elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a tower too early will let your opponent freeze the lane too far in and catch up with you and maybe even eventually beat you. Don't rush taking the tower, instead wait until you can see that you are ahead and you want to start roaming to win other lanes...